# My son has passed and I need a Snapchat filter removed. Please help!

Tags: layers

My son passed at 17 years old recently and my favorite picture of him smiling is with his girlfriend with a Snapchat filter of hearts on it. He isn’t smiling much in any other pictures I have of him although he smiled all the time just not for pictures. I so want this picture to be used on his gravestone. Is there anyone who can help me get these hearts off this picture? I am not very photo savvy. Thanks in advance

Comment: I’m so sorry for your loss. Unfortunately, Snapchat does not save an unfiltered version of its images, and the filters are not added non-destructively, so short of airbrushing and recreating the missing bits, I don’t think there is any way of removing the hearts.

Comment: As @JanusBahsJacquet says, such filters cannot be easily removed. However a photo restoration artist, or even an artist who specialises in drawing portraits may be able to do this for you. Probably the best idea is to call one, and get an estimate.

Answer (score 7):

Reddit is a popular social news website that has a "subreddit" called [/r/PhotoshopRequest](https://www.reddit.com/r/PhotoshopRequest/) specifically for this kind of image editing requests.

Create a Reddit account and upload your photo there and I'm sure you will get the help you need.